# CodeIgniter inserting apostrophes in to database query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, substring, apostrophe

I have a bit of a strange problem that has been baffling me.  All I am trying to do is run a query on a database table but for some reason, CodeIgniter is putting apostrophes into the query which is subsequently breaking the page.

My code looks like this:

```
$this->db->select("SUBSTRING(body,5)"); 
$this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
$this->data['query'] = $this->db->get_where('blog-entries', array('status' => 'P'), 3);
```

But I get an error on this page:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`blog-entries`) WHERE `status` = 'P' ORDER BY `date` desc LIMIT 3' at line 2
```

The query is actually being run as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(body, `5)` FROM (`blog-entries`) WHERE `status` = 'P' ORDER BY `date` desc LIMIT 3
```

As you can see for some reason apostrophes have been added around the number 5 within the substring.  If I remove the substring then everything works and if I remove the apostrophes and run the query directly on my db it also works.

Has any got any ideas as to why this may be happening or have a solution?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

G.

Comment: It's actually back-ticks being added, not apostrophes. Just to clarify.

Comment: Does adding `FALSE` as a second parameter, like this `$this->db->select("SUBSTRING(body,5)", FALSE); ` fix it? It should stop CodeIgniter adding backticks.

Comment: that's why I HATE these silly query builders, making simple queries into screen-high blocks of spaghetti

Comment: To be fair, most of them also have an option to just manually type out the entire query without using a builder. You have a choice.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$this->db->select("SUBSTRING(body,5)", FALSE);
```

As a default, Codeigniter tries to add back-ticks where it thinks is relevant. Sometimes it adds them where it shouldn't. Passing `FALSE` as the second parameter prevents it from doing this.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply.  This does get rid of the database error, however, it doesnt appear to run the query as I get error on the page where I am writing out the fields from the query:

Comment: I get the "Message: Undefined property" error message.  I am going to try and grab the 'body' field and substring it directly outputting the field from the controller rather then the whole query.

Comment: Actually, I think I realise whats happening.  I just need to add the other fields into the SELECT!

Comment: I ended up going down the route of defining the entire query rather than using the query builder.  Thanks very much for your help guys!